# Why cordless hammer drill possess such few markets in Europe?What's the difference between hammer drill and impact drill?

Tags: electrical, remodeling

Recently, I found in a GfK data report that cordless hammer drills have very little market share in Europe. But to my opinion, we use it very often when doing home improvement or building something. What on earth is the reason? Very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you why a market does or doesn't adopt a tool, but I can tell you the difference:

A hammer drill has a device in it that provides lateral motion down the tool as if you had a regular drill and somebody was hitting the back of it with a hammer.

An impact driver is like having a that you smack with a hammer in the direction you want it turn.

A good link for this with a few more words: http://www.thewoodwhisperer.com/articles/drills-vs-hammer-drills-vs-impact-drivers/

Answer (score 0):

I wondered the same thing the other day, why my cordless drill that I bought in Poland.. have no hammer action.. How the heck am i supposed to drill into that masonry brick without burning my bits?

So, IN UK I went onto ebay, tesco direct, B&Q and all the cordless drills are without action hamemr.. under £50 kits. You can get them but you need to fork out much more cash.

I suspect they badge that type of equipment professional tools and the prices are just out of home DIY'ers price range.. but a pro knows all to well to go and spend that extra so he can get the job done properly.

> In economics/politics, if there is no clear answer, its usually about
>   making money.

Which is odd, because when I lived in South Africa, all the cordless drills that I bought in these warehouse type DIY stores.. had impact cordless drills.. for under £50